# How to pass postData using ng-href

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, angular-ui, export-to-excel

I have the following scenario. I am doing an excel export. It works fine when I use ng-href by passing just one ID in query string. But now I have multiple ID's to pass, So I am using ng-click in HTML and $http.POST that passes postData to the server as shown below. The problem is if I use ng-click and call $http.post, it gets the required data but it wont create the excel document. I think it is because I am not using ng-href, but cant figure out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="transmission-buttons" data-ng-show="resultsReturned">
        <!--<a ng-href="../ExcelDownload/ExcelDownload.aspx?workListID={{selectedExportWorkListID}}" class="btn btn-info pull-right" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>Export to Excel</a>-->
        <a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="" ng-click="getWorklistExportData($event)" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>Export to Excel</a>
        </div>
```

Controller.JS:

```
$scope.getWorklistExportData = function (e) {
    rest.post('../ExcelDownload/ExcelDownload.aspx', $scope.selectedWorkListIDs).success(function (resp) {
        var successResp = resp;
        e.preventDefault();

    }).error(function (resp) {
        var errResp = resp;
    });

}
```

aspx.cs:

```
public partial class ExcelDownload_ExcelDownload : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        var stream = sr.ReadToEnd();
        CreateExcel(stream);
        //CreateExcel(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["workListID"]));
        //CreateExcel(823);
    }
```

}

```
    private void CreateExcel(string cbrIdList)
{
    var client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIBCOServer"]);

    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportWorklistCBRS"];
    //url = url.Replace("{workListID}", workListID.ToString());

    var request = CreateStandardRestRequest(url, Method.POST);

    request.RootElement = "WorkListDetailExport";
    request.AddParameter("CBR_ID", cbrIdList, ParameterType.RequestBody);


    var queryResult = client.Execute<List<CBRSRecord>>(request);
    var queryResult2 = client.Execute(request);

    DataTable tbl = ToDataTable<CBRSRecord>(queryResult.Data);

    tbl = FormatColumnNames(tbl);
    // DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worklist");

        //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

        for (int x = 1; x < 50; x++)
        {
            ws.Column(x).AutoFit();
        }
        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:AB1"])
        {
            rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=WorkList" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: It will be downloading the excel spreadsheet either way, however when using `$http.post` you are making an ajax request so the response is in the variable resp, passed to your success function.

Comment: Looking at the code you have posted, whether the excel document gets created or not depends on what your CreateExcel() method is doing, which isn't posted.

Comment: Looking at the `CreateExcel()` method, is there any change that would need to be made to it if you were to go back to using `ng-href`?

Comment: I cannot go back to ng-href, coz I have to pass multiple ID's in postData. If I use ng-href, I have to pass in query string which will limit the number of ID's that I can pass.

Comment: @NaveenReddy Did you figure it out? I'm having the same scenario.

Comment: Yes I am doing $Http.Post in button click and then passing all the data in PostData. Once it reach to the server, I am saving all the post data in Session Object. Once the data is saved in session it returns back to the Success callback of $Http.Post. Here in the success callback I am calling window.open as shown below..